# Filtering Users in MSGraph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to filter users by attributes in Microsoft Graph API. Essentially trying to get a list of users that have a given `jobTitle` assigned.

For example, `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=jobtitle eq 'ACCOUNT EXECUTIVE'` returns a list of users.

My requirement is to query for users that do not have a `JobTitle`.

Tried `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=jobtitle ne null` and got the following message.

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": "Unsupported property filter clause operator 'NotEqualsMatch'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "c9b290bf-2902-4b79-b35b-0f5d251ad80b",
            "date": "2017-09-14T11:18:52"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`$filter=department ge '!'` appears to be a workaround here.

Comment: Why does this work? This did exactly what I needed it to do. What's the significance with the '!'?

Comment: $filter=department ge ' ' (with a space) might be even better.
The query works because the  '!' is the second printable character in the ASCII table (the space is the first, that why I say it could be even better)
http://www.asciitable.com/
Brilliant idea Leon!

Answer (score 2):

According to this Git Issue, I don't think it's supported: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/239 (it eventually just revolves around finding rooms)

> There is no way to filter the users collection for entities with surname equal to null or empty string. The value of the filter must be between 1 and 64 characters as documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#userentity - marych Apr 26, 2016
>
> The lack of null filtering is due to the way users are indexed. We can't efficiently retrieve users with an indexed property unset. There are no plans to change that. - marych May 13, 2016